# Does Virtuoso store triple creation timestamp?

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I would like to know whether a triple creation timestamp exists somewhere in `Virtuoso` `RDF` store and, if yes, can it be retrieved, assuming it was not explicitly created as the object of its own triple that would be associated to its subject by convention. I would like to list all the triples in my `graph` by their creation timestamp.

If the following query:

```
select * from <http://my.graph> {
?s ?p ?o .
}
```

returns something like

```
s                     |p                    |o  |
----------------------|---------------------|---|
http://my.domain/subj |http://var.def#var1  |X  |
http://my.domain/subj |http://var.def#var2  |Y  |
```

I would like to actually know the time each of the listed triples were created, if Virtuoso has that data in hiding somewhere.

Comment: No, that would be your task to add such meta-data on insertion time.

Comment: As this is a follow-up question, I'm wondering whether you really want the triple creation timestamp, or if that is just the mechanism you think will be easiest for your `ORDER BY` clause. It feels like we're pursuing [a sequence of XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), rather than addressing your actual need.

Comment: I have a workaround for the ORDER BY but would also like to know the timestamp of each triple creation, if there is a way to retrieve it. Storing it explicitly would require creating a whole new triple, unless there is a way to widen it into a quadruple to make room for the extra piece of information.  it's not an XY question. you can relax and take my inquiries at face value rather than try to read into...

Comment: the workaround is not perfect but is good enough. i order by the subject alphabetically to fetch all the data in a graph in batches and I offset the next batch by the last item in the previous batch, the query being `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid dupes.  the reason that is not perfect is because during batch #3 someone can enter a triple whose subject alphanumerically goes in the first batch so the process will miss it.  but if I had a timestamp and ordered by it, the new triple would go in the last batch, meaning the last batch would pick up all the remaining unread triples.

Comment: thanks @AKSW -- but what is not clear to me is whether that data would be the object attribute of its own triple or would there be a way to store it somewhere in an existing triple whose object is something else.  IOW if my triple is `A-B-C`, is there a way to fit the timestamp somewhere inside the triple or would I have to create a new triple `A-timestamp_key-timestamp_val` and associate it with A-B-C by the subject A ? the former would be what i need because the latter would only mean that the timestamp is associated with its own triple but the other triple could be created at another time

Comment: the latter deign could work if assumed that all the triples associated with subject A are created at the same time, which is not too terrible

Comment: @amphibient It doesn't make sense to attach the timestamp to the subject A as there could be many triples with the same subject. You have to use reification of RDF triples, which is documented here https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-mt-20140225/#whatnot , An example could be `_:x rdf:type rdf:Statement .
_:x rdf:subject :Tolkien .
_:x rdf:predicate :wrote .
_:x rdf:object :LordOfTheRings .
_:x :timestamp 123344421 .`